# What does need to be corrected for my solution in order for it to work properly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

UPDATE: I figured out the solution on my own. instead of doing the solutions below, a simpler solution is

**CODE SOURCE**

let trUp = (chord)=>{

let index= arr.indexOf(chord);
 return arr.IndedOf(index) - 1;

}

Comment: why not take an array? it is suited for ordered content.

Comment: How exactly would I implement that? Because I don't really see how I would use an array for this issue? What I mean is I'm not able to visualize it as you are.

Comment: Please give your questions a more descriptive title, so that other users with a similar problem can find it.

Comment: @alroithmhelp Why did you remove the entire description of the problem? Please do not deface questions making them incomprehensible to future visitors. Edit rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and look for the index and increment by adjusting by the length of the array with the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).

```js
function up(note) {
    return notes[(notes.indexOf(note) + 1) % notes.length];
}

var notes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];

console.log(up('C'));
```

Comment: Its not working, look at my new  code based on your code( I modified it)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly longer version that would allow you to transpose single chords or an array of chords either up / down...

```
const chordMap = ['A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#'];
```

Define some functions to move chords either up or down 1 and return the result

```
function chordUp(chord) {
    let index = chordMap.indexOf(chord) + 1;
    if (index >= chordMap.length) index = 0;
    return chordMap[index];
}

function chordDown(chord) {
    let index = chordMap.indexOf(chord) - 1;
    if (index < 0) index = chordMap.length - 1;
    return chordMap[index];
}
```

Then functions to transpose an entire array of chords up or down 1 and return the results as an array

```
function transposeUp(input) {
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let chord = input[i];
        output.push(chordUp(chord));
    }
    return output;
}

function transposeDown(input) {
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let chord = input[i];
        output.push(chordDown(chord));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Finally you can use it like so...

```
let chords = ['A', 'G#', 'B', 'C#',  'A#', 'G'];

let transposedUp = transposeUp(chords); // [ "A#", "A", "C", "D", "B", "G#" ];
let transposedDown = transposeDown(chords) // [ "G#", "G", "A#", "C", "A", "F#" ];
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that behaviour - I've updated my answer to include 'G' in the array of chords and the comments with real results that I saw when testing

Comment: Yeah but you're not inputing more than 11 values, I'm dealing with 13 and sometimes 18 values. so can you test that please? I'm very curios.

Comment: I've just created this jsfiddle and it supplies 20 values https://jsfiddle.net/x7w2oqds/7/

Comment: Ah weird, I don't understand why its not working for me :( it does the first 3 steps right, then it starts to skip 1 then do the work. for example. "E" becomes , "F" then "G" then if i do it one more time, it will be "A#" not even "G#" or "A"

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of the code that's causing that on something like jsfiddle?